# Is it possible to install ArcPy on a server for use in a geoprocessing web application?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a website on my intranet and would like to add some geoprocessing tools to it with Python.

Many Users will not have Arc installed on their machines, so I think I need to have the scripts set up in such a way that they are not dependant on the traditional mappings.

I have Python installed on my server and set up IIS to run scripts on the serverside.
currently running the "HelloWorld.py".

Is there a way to install ArcPy on my server?

Any ideas would be welcome.

Andy

Comment: Do you mean install it independently of ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Server?

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS for Desktop does not need to be installed for users to have access to Geoprocessing Services that have ArcPy imported into their code.

However, you need ArcGIS for Server to publish those Geoprocessing Services.

Here is an overview of [Geoprocessing Services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004v5000000).